# ASP.NET Website keeps signing out randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my local version of my site, you are free to roam with no problem. However when running off of the built version on the web, you are randomly logged out.

It happens whenever I click out of the Internet Window, but it also does it between page loads.

My web config is seen below,

```
    <!--CONNECTION STRING-->
<connectionStrings>
<add name="RaiseFantasyLeagueConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MATT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Raise;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
<sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
<!--MEMBERSHIP-->
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager">
    <providers>
        <add name="SqlRoleManager" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="RaiseFantasyLeagueConnectionString" applicationName="MyApplication" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
    <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="RaiseFantasyLeagueConnectionString" applicationName="Raise Fantasy League" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"/>
    </providers>
    </membership>
    <!--AUTHENTICATION-->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="RaiseFLAuthentication" loginUrl="home.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="/myPredictions.aspx" timeout="240"/></authentication>
    <!--AUTHORIZATION-->
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

I was told to put  into my web config, but this has not solved the problem.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Another issue I am having is that from the home page, if I log in I am not taken to the defult URL, just a 404 page. The URL does not even change from the default address.

Can anyone see why that may be happening?

Comment: did you check the IIS configuration? Here's how to set a session timeout in the IIS.

[link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @iZ88 - it's about authentication/cookie/ticket expiration - not session.

Comment: @AspDevel - are you generating the authentication ticket manually - it might have different timeout than the form